# count decimal places with Access query

Tags: ms-access

please give me the SQL to count the decimal places in the unit_Price in my Access 2007 query
thank you very much

`SELECT SYSADM_PART.ID, SYSADM_PART.UNIT_PRICE
FROM SYSADM_PART;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be something like this (but I haven't tried it):

```
SELECT 
   SYSADM_PART.ID, 
   SYSADM_PART.UNIT_PRICE, 
   (Len([SYSADM_PART.UNIT_PRICE]) - InStrRev(Str([SYSADM_PART.UNIT_PRICE]), ".")) AS decimal_places
FROM SYSADM_PART
```

This is an educated guess. I assumed Unit_Price is a number, thats why I have converted to a string.

Apologies, if this is wrong.

Let me know if it works, I don't have anyway to try it!

Answer (score 0):

This would use Mid() and coerce the numeric values to strings. The Mid() and InStr() functions do implicit coercion within Access, but I don't know if the Jet versions of those will do the same, so I've written it with explicit type conversion.

```
SELECT SYSADM_PART.ID, SYSADM_PART.UNIT_PRICE, 
  Len(Mid(CStr(SYSADM_PART.UNIT_PRICE), InStr(CStr(SYSADM_PART.UNIT_PRICE) + 1, "."))) AS decimal_places
FROM SYSADM_PART
```

Note also that this won't work with Nulls nor with UNIT_PRICE values that lack a decimal point. If the field has Nulls, or values without decimal points, this would work:

```
SELECT SYSADM_PART.ID, SYSADM_PART.UNIT_PRICE, 
  IIf(IsNull(SYSADM_PART.UNIT_PRICE) Or (InStr(SYSADM_PART.UNIT_PRICE, ".") = 0), 0, Len(Mid(CStr(SYSADM_PART.UNIT_PRICE), InStr(CStr(SYSADM_PART.UNIT_PRICE) + 1, ".")))) AS decimal_places
FROM SYSADM_PART
```

I may have misbalanced the parens, but you get the idea.